# How to get the max of all the named categories in a pandas table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So imagine I have data like this:

```
  name  time
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    B     3
3    A     6
4    A     7
5    A     3
6    B     1
7    B     4
```

Each entry has a named category and some other information. In the example above lets take time. Its the only one i care about.

I would like to produce a table which has just the individual unique `name` categopries and the max of each. I can do something like this:

```
max_table = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": data.name.unique(),
        "max_val": [
            data[data["name"] == name].time.max() for name in data.name.unique()
        ],
    }
)
```

But this does not feel very pandas-y. I have to go to and from the pandas table between lists and do some array expansion to make this work. **Is there a way to do this with just a pandas type call?**

*Full example including data creation:*

```
    data = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "name": pd.Categorical(["A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"]),
            "time": [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 1, 4],
        }
    )
    print(data)
    print("======================")

    max_table = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "name": data.name.unique(),
            "max_val": [
                data[data["name"] == name].time.max() for name in data.name.unique()
            ],
        }
    )
    print(max_table)
```

Comment: Something like the (rough) `df.groupby('name').max().reset_index()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to get to know about `Pandas` or `Numpy` is **Vectorized** manipulation(like **Matlab** dealing data with matrix/arrays). Which can process multiple items of data at once instead of `for` loop operation.

`groupby()` clustering data into groups, and `max()` find the maximum value of each group.

```
output = df.groupby('name').max()
output
###
      time
name      
A        7
B        4
```

The remaining part is just to reconstruct the table(DataFrame) structure.

(As you can see, `name` is lower than `time`, which means `name` is set to be index of the table(DataFrame), and `time` is a column's name of the table)

```
output = output.reset_index().rename(columns={'time':'max_time'})
output
###
  name  max_time
0    A         7
1    B         4
```

Comment: Best answer by far for outputting using groupby!

Answer (score 2):

A bit cleaner:

```
out = df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['time'].agg({'max_time': 'max'})
print(out)
```

Output:

```
  name  max_time
0    A         7
1    B         4
```

Comment: omg, so short and easy. How can i express this to google such that it shows me answers like this?

Comment: Pandas grouping aggregation, here's a [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
output = data.groupby('name')['time'].max()
```

Output:

```
Name
A  7
B  4
```